# not able to start or stop shiny-server on RedHat AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, shiny-server

I've got shiny installed and running on a RedHat AWS EC2 instance. However, it seems to be forever running, because typing `stop shiny-server` or `start shiny-server` results in the error: `-bash: restart: command not found`. I don't see this when I install shiny on a Ubuntu instance. Is there a way to fix this on RedHat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using RedHat 7, so you should use systemd:

```
sudo systemctl start shiny-server
sudo systemctl stop shiny-server
sudo systemctl restart shiny-server
```

Comment: Useful answer. there should be more up vote for that!